# Change specific property

Tags: c#, json, postman

How do I change the `CourseName` from `History` to `Gym` if the `ID` is equally to `2`?

```
{
  "Result": {
    "StudentInfo": {
      "ID": 20,
      "Name": "Bob",
      "IgnoreThis": [
        {
          "ID": 123,
          "Something":"abc"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Courses": [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "CourseName":"Math"
      },
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "CourseName":"History"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This code below is just a fantasy code to show what I had in mind:

```
{ "Result":{ "Course" : [ if id=2 inside "Courses" then "CourseName":"Gym" ] }}
```

I will be using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal C#, I tried to achieve this by just JSON in Postman application before I solve this on C# in my project.

Comment: use Json.NET for this

Comment: @IgorSemin Is this not possible without a plugin?

Comment: @ipid, yup, it's not

Comment: @IgorSemin Ok thanks. Is this not either achievable with just using JSON in Postman as well? Asking for getting better understanding about using JSON.

Comment: i think u can use this link https://www.getpostman.com/docs/testing_examples for this feature

Comment: @IgorSemin Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works (it could possibly be tidied up); it does however use `Newtonsoft.Json` (a well-known nuget package).

```cs
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string blah = "{'Result': { 'StudentInfo': { 'ID': 20, 'Name': 'Bob', 'IgnoreThis': [{'ID': 123,'Something':'abc'}]}, 'Courses': [{'ID': 1,'CourseName':'Math'},{'ID': 2,'CourseName':'History'}]}}";

            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(blah);
            var dynamicJson = json.Result.Courses; // included to show how dynamic could be accessed instead

            JObject arr = json;

            foreach (var course in arr["Result"]["Courses"].Where(x => x["ID"].Value<int>() == 2))
            {
                course["CourseName"] = "Gym";
            }

            var newResult = json.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```